# how to access --- i/o Port from kernel space driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

i am able to access the i/o port in the `user space` using `mmap` system call on `/dev/mem`

```
#define BCM2708_PERI_BASE       0x20000000
#define GPIO_PADS               (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x100000)
#define CLOCK_BASE              (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x101000)
#define GPIO_BASE               (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x200000)
#define GPIO_PWM                (BCM2708_PERI_BASE + 0x20C000)


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static volatile uint32_t *gpio;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int fd ;

        //Obtain handle to physical memory
        if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC) ) < 0) {
                printf("Unable to open /dev/mem: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
        }


        //map a page of memory to gpio at offset 0x20200000 which is where GPIO goodnessstarts
        gpio = (uint32_t *)mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x20200000);

        if ((int32_t)gpio < 0){
                printf("Mmap failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
                return -1;
        }

        //set gpio17 as an output
        //increment the pointer to 0x20200004
        //set the value through a little bit twiddling where we only modify the bits 21-23 in the register
        *(gpio + 1) = (*(gpio + 1) & ~(7 << 21)) | (1 << 21);

        //toggle gpio17 every second
        while(1){
                //set the pin high
                //increment the pointer to 0x2020001C
                *(gpio + 7) = 1 << 17;

                //sleep
                sleep(1);

                //set the pin to low
                //increment the pointer to 0x20200028
                *(gpio + 10) = 1 << 17;

                sleep(1);
        }
}
```

Map will only work in user space. Now how can i access the same i/o port in the `kernel space`  device driver `?`

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983356/kernel-function-definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every module for ex: GPIO module has its own memory map i.e. physical address specified in the processor's technical reference manual. First you need to check if the memory region is being used or not using `check_mem_region`.  If it is free request access to this memory region using `request_mem_region`, then map the GPIO module using `ioremap` or `ioremap_nocache` (map bus memory into CPU space), which returns a void pointer. The returned address is not guaranteed to be usable directly as a virtual address; it is only usable by `ioread*|iowrite*|read*|write*`, etc. functions.  Use `ioread8|16|32/iowrite8|16|32` functions to read or write from/to i/o ports. Finally you need to `iounmap` to unmap the memory and then you need to release memory region using `release_mem_region`. Usually in kernel space, most of the time **there is no need check and request for the memory region**. You only need to map bus memory into CPU space using `ioremap` or `ioremap_nocache` and unmap using `iounmap`.

Comment: .. But how come in my AT91RM9200 board from ATmel, I am simply using MACROS to acess the GPIO PORTS of the controller . Are these implementation hidden in header files ?

Comment: Yes for ex: "Blackfin ADSPBF512" from "Analog Devices" also use MACROS which in-turn calls wrapper function and it internally calls actual i/o port accessing function as above. Core implementation codes, accessing the i/o ports functions are hidden(can land up to the actual i/o port access function, need to go through in depth of GPIO driver).

Comment: While you don't need to request the memory region, I firmly believe that your driver should request the memory region.  Checking the memory region first with `check_mem_region` is deprecated as with SMP, it is always possible that the memory has been claimed by another module between the time you check it and the time you request it.  Simply always look at the return value of `request_mem_region`.

Comment: @Benjamin, thanks. Tried to explain in depth, so talked about check_mem_region. Need to check only the request_mem_region return value and go ahead map and access the i/o port.