# Kernel Function definitions

Tags: linux-kernel, cross-reference

Where can I find the complete implementation/body of the following functions, defined as a function prototype in "include/linux/pci.h" in the Linux Kernel.

```
int pci_bus_read_config_byte (struct pci_bus *bus, unsigned int devfn, int where, u8 *val);
int pci_bus_write_config_byte (struct pci_bus *bus, unsigned int devfn, int where, u8 val);
```

I usually use [free-electron's cross reference](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/) to find definitions of functions in the kernel. I've also used [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) to find the definitions of these functions but with no luck in both cases.

Comment: If you voted for my answer and find it satisfactory, please accept it. :)

Comment: @microMolvi Answer below gets it, but to be more specific/direct the PCI config space is read/written on x86 platforms using ioport calls on ports 0xCFC and 0xCF8.

Comment: @PeterL. Thankyou for pointing that out. I hope it will be helpful to me in the future and to many in present. For the time being I am trying to port a PCIe driver to U-boot on an ARM based platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't find them using a "dumb" indexer/tagger because they are generated by macros [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pci/access.c).